# Optimal way to animate multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for the best way to animate several divs onscreen. I tried jQuery, but it started getting skippy after I had > 5 elements on the screen. Raphael.js gave me the same problem. So, what is the best way to animate 5-6 divs on a screen at once? They're just moving horizontally across the screen.

Would CSS3's translate2d be good for this? I recall reading somewhere that you can severely optimize performance by using translate3d instead. Is that applicable in my case?

Comment: can you post the code that does your animations?

Comment: You can try the css3 transformation stuff. However, different browsers will, perform differntly. Also, some will use hardware acceleration, so results may vary from machine to machine.

Comment: @Joseph, I don't really have any code. I'm just trying to find the best way to write it. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville then at least post the code that was problematic

Comment: It was just a standard jQuery animation, nothing special whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target browsers support CSS3, you can achieve much smoother animations using `translate2d`. If you need to animate all items together (i.e. the animation rules are the same for each one of them), you can just create a class

```
.animTarget{animation:translate3d(100, 0, 0)}
```

And then in your javascript code, say:

```
$("animation-target-selector").addClass('animTarget')
```

I have found that animating things like this is easier than doing something like:

```
$("animation-target-selector").css('animation', 'translate3d(100, 100, 0)');
```

Because it adds it to the `style` attribute of each and every dom element.